# Including values from external table in a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to write LINQ query for following SQL query:

```
    SELECT A.ID
    FROM TABLE_1 A, TABLE_2 B
    WHERE A.ID = B.ID
    AND B.STATEID IN (SELECT C.STATEID FROM STATE C WHERE C.REGIONID = 1)
```

For this I've managed to make following query:

```
    var var1 = (from a in db.table_1
                join b in db.table_2
                on a.Id equals b.Id
                where b.stateid = 
                select new
                {
                   a.Id
                }).ToList();)
```

Here how can I include all the **StateIDs** where **RegionId** is **1** to get the necessary output.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? And what do you actually receive? I think you have to join the Tables

Comment: How about a join?

Answer (score 0):

Your equivalent Linq query would be something:

```
var result = (from a in db.table_1
              from b in db.table_2 
               where a.Id == b.Id
               && db.State.Any(c=>c.REGIONID  == 1 && b.StateId == c.StateId) 
                select new
                {
                   a.Id
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Will this compile?

Comment: @RahulSingh thanks for pointing out, i think it should be `Any` here like you  posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx):-

```
where db.States.Any(x => x.RegionId == 1 &&  x.StateId == b.StateId)
select...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
var var1 = (from a in db.table_1
            join b in db.table_2
            on a.Id equals b.Id
            where db.State.Any(c=> c.RegionId == 1 && c.StateId == b.StateId)
            select new
            {
               a.Id
            }).ToList();)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var var1 = (from a in db.table_1
                join b in db.table_2
                on a.Id equals b.Id
                where (db.State.Where(x => x.RegionId == 1).Select(x => 
                       x.StateId)).Contains(b.Id)
                select new
                {
                   a.Id
                }).ToList();)
```